# All linear combinations of a set of vectors that equal a specific vector

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a set $S$ of vectors, say,
$$S=\{[4,6,2],[8,3,8],[2,4,5] \}.$$

How can I get all linear combinations of these vectors such that the linear combination will equal $[180,180,90]$ ?

edit:

I should be more specific, I am concerned with a set $S$ of arbitrary size. if the size of $S$ is greater than $3$, I will have free variables in my solution, right? Doesn't that mean that there are infinitely many solutions to the equality

suppose I am interested in all of those such that all constant multiples of the vectors in $S$ are greater than $0$. How would I go about finding the existence, and the exact values of such constants.

Comment: Have you tried solving the 3 simulatenous linear equations $\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 = u$? where $v_i$ are the vectors of $S$ and $u$ is your given vector?

Comment: I should be more specific, I am concerned with a set S of arbitrary size. if the size of S is greater than 3, I will have free variables in my solution, right? Doesn't that mean that there are infinitely many solutions to the equality.

Comment: Perhaps you need to rephrase your question then. For instance, are you working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or in a more general setting? Is your set $S$ linearly independent?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post. I may be dealing with a linearly dependent set.

Answer (score 2):

You're interested in numbers $x,y,z$ such that
$$
x(4,6,2) + y(8,3,8) + z(2,4,5) = (180,180,90)
$$
Looking at the coordinates in the first position, this implies that:
$$
4x + 8y + 2z = 180
$$
You can get two more similar equations by looking at the second and third coordinates. So, in the end, you get a system of 3 equations that you can solve to get $x,y,z$.

If you're unlucky, this system of equations might not have any solutions. That might be the whole point of the question -- the number of solutions is dictated by the linear dependence (or independence) of the three given vectors.